# Definitive download location for MBSA "wsusscn2.cab" file for offline mode scans?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, update

I'm running *Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer 2.1* against some servers that don't have outbound access to the Internet, by design of firewall restrictions, and therefore I'm wishing to run MBSA in **offline mode**.

In order to do so, I need the list of updates in the file named **"wsusscn2.cab"**.  Is there a well-known page or URL at Microsoft for downloading the most up-to-date version of that file for MBSA offline mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MBSA FAQ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184922.aspx):
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=76054

Comment: This link is now outdated. The new link is http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=74689. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926464 for more details.